# How update correctly a database in symfony2?

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, production-environment

The official documentation of Symfony2 says that:

"Whether or not you take advantage of migrations, the doctrine:schema:update command should only
be used during development. It should not be used in a production environment."

Then what is the correct way to update a database in a prod environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Doctrine migration bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).

It helps you to generate non-destructive for your db.

Doctrine migration bundle offers to generate for you, based upon your schema changes, all the queries to generate the migrations (up and down, so you can "switch" between migrations) and, moreover, you can generate queries (so even insert, delete, update and so on) that could be executed in "safe way".

Otherwise you can use [Symfony console commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) (that you need to write by yourself) to handle those kind of situation.

To me migration bundle is the safest way: you can even automate the `doctrine:migration:migrate` command in your deploy script or process so you will not risk to deploy a version of software without correct version of db schema